# How can display listview from a datatable?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is design xaml: it include a listview display list image, title, subtilte.

```
             <ListView  x:Name="listView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                        Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding image}" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding title}"
                                TextColor="#f35e20" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding subtitle}"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#503026" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I add process  load data to listview:

```
public ListAccount ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("image");
            dt.Columns.Add("title");
            dt.Columns.Add("subtitle");
            var dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["image"] = "a.jpg";
            dr["title"] = "title";
            dr["subtitle"] = "subtitle1";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            listView.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView ;
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Why row not display?

How can display listview from a datatable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Datatable try Model as below. It will display more beatiful

```
public ListAccount()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<ItemModel> itemModels = new List<ItemModel>();
        itemModels.Add(new ItemModel()
        {
            Image = "Image1",
            SubTitle = "Subbtitle1",
            Title = "Title1"
        });
        itemModels.Add(new ItemModel()
        {
            Image = "Image2",
            SubTitle = "Subbtitle2",
            Title = "Title2"
        });
        listView.ItemsSource = itemModels;
    }

    public class ItemModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

XAML Code:

```
 <ListView  x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                            TextColor="#f35e20" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding SubTitle}"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            TextColor="#503026" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a type:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    // more properties

    public MyType(string title, /* more arguments */)
    {
        this.title = title;
        /* set more properties from arguments */ 
    }
}
```

Set `ItemsSource`:

```
listView.ItemsSource = 
    dt.Select().ToList().Select(r =>
        new MyType(r["title"] as string, /* more arguments */));
```

Answer (score 0):

Any platform-specific code is not supported in a PCL. As with any platform-specific view you will need to implement a custom renderer. This [blog post](https://www.wintellect.com/supercharging-xamarin-forms-with-custom-renderers-part-1) describes how to do that.